# Angular url change does not cause the component to be recreated

Tags: angular, router, paging

I have a component that lists a series of data and needs paging, because the list of data can be long.
I have implemented a simple paging using the route. For example:

```
http://localhost:50367/searchflights/2
```

Will give me the second page of data.
Now **if I type the url manually in the browser and press enter** the component is *forced* to be recreated and for this reason the data are loaded in the constructor.
But If I am already on the page of the component and via Router link change the url, only the url changes and the component is not recreated therefore data are not reloaded.

My paging consists in a simple list of links at the bottom of page:

```
<div>
        <a style="display:inline-block" *ngFor="let page of pages" [routerLink]="['/searchflights/',page]">
            {{page}}
        </a>
    </div>
```

If I click on one of the paging links, the route is changed accordingly but data are not reloaded.
How can I force the recreation of the component or which event should I hook to in order to reload the data

Comment: Have you tried using `{{page}}` in the `[routerLink]`?

Comment: I have tried clicking on the router link and this just causes the route to change, but component is not recreated. I need to press the refresh button to see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the route parameters instead of loading data in the constructor.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.loadUser(params.id);
});
```